# How can I use IOTA in Arduino Mega?

Tags: sensor, arduino

I'm currently trying to use IOTA in an arduino mega that has a lora Shield and send data to another one (node to node connection with lora shield).
How can I use IOTA to secure this transaction?

Comment: Why do you think IOTA could be of any help here? What is your goal you want to use IOTA for? Please clarify the question.